# pandas remove equal rows by comparing columns in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df1 = [['tom', 10, 1.2], ['nick', 15, 1.3], ['juli', 14, 1.4]]
```

[image]

```
df1 = [['tom', 10, 1.2], ['nick', 15, 1.3], ['juli', 100, 1.4]]
```

[image]

When I am trying compare and remove equal using below code

```py
diff = df1.compare(df2, align_axis=1, keep_equal=True, keep_shape=True).drop_duplicates(
    keep=False).rename(index={'self': 'df1', 'other': 'df2'}, level=-1)
```

I am getting

[image]

I want to keep only that row which has any unequal records and remove remaining. It means only last row should be present in output not all rows like blow. Please suggest changes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want everything from df1 that does not matches df2

```
n_columns = len(df1.columns)
df1[(df1 == df2).apply(sum, axis=1).apply(lambda x: x != n_columns)]
```

Comment: Hi @Prashant, I want to return only that row which has differences. like below: